# How to connect to arduino and view services within android app?

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am currently using an Arduino Nano 33 BLE to calculate an angle measurement from an IMU and add these values to a Bluetooth characteristic within a service. I create the service and characteristic using the ArduinoBLE library:

```
BLEService angleService("1826");
BLEFloatCharacteristic rollBLE("2A57", BLERead | BLENotify);
```

Within my setup, I set the device's name, service, and characteristic. I initially write a value of 0 to the characteristic:

```
BLE.setLocalName("acsAssist");
BLE.setAdvertisedService(angleService);
angleService.addCharacteristic(rollBLE);
BLE.addService(angleService);
rollBLE.writeValue(0);
BLE.advertise();
```

Within my loop, after I perform my calculation, I change the value of the characteristic accordingly:

```
rollBLE.writeValue(posiRoll);            // posiRoll is my calculation
```

When I use a third party app like nrfConnect on my Android device, I am able to find my device and connect to it. The service and characteristic I defined is present and the value is changing as expected:

[Here is the output from the nrfConnect app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyiWM.jpg)

Now, I am attempting to manually connect to this device within the Android app that I'm building so that I can display this changing value on the screen for the user to see. I include all of the following permissions in my Manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I begin by checking that the device the user is using has a bluetooth adapter, and that it is on:

```
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {                     // Bluetooth not supported
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This device does not support Bluetooth! Use a Bluetooth enabled device.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {                // If adapter is not enabled, request to enable it from within the app
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }

        if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
```

Since I know the MAC address of the arduino, I try to get the device using that MAC address. When I do this, I am able to view attributes such as the device name and address. However, when I try to view the UUIDs of the arduino, I receive 'null'. The followning code:

```
BluetoothDevice arduino = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("E5:A5:53:32:BD:7C");
Log.i("DEVICES", String.valueOf(arduino.getName()));
Log.i("DEVICES", String.valueOf(arduino.getAddress()));
Log.i("DEVICES", String.valueOf(arduino.getUuids()));
```

produces the resulting output in the logcat:

```
02-11 12:09:02.862 29503-29503/com.seniorproject.acsAssistApp I/DEVICES: acsAssist
02-11 12:09:02.862 29503-29503/com.seniorproject.acsAssistApp I/DEVICES: E5:A5:53:32:BD:7C
02-11 12:09:02.868 29503-29503/com.seniorproject.acsAssistApp I/DEVICES: null
```

I have been trying to figure out how to connect my app to the arduino and view the services that I created, but I am at a loss for how to do that. All the guides, Q&As, and documentation I have tried to find related to this has left me feeling hopeless and confused. Any guidance on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I apologize if my formatting for this submission is poor. This is my very first time submitting a question on Stack Overflow. I am also a **completely new beginner** with Arduino and Android Development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the answer to my difficulties. I was over-complicating the situation; instead I have decided to take advantage of the GATT properties of my implementation. First,  I get the adapter and the arduino via MAC address.

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
BluetoothDevice arduino = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("E5:A5:53:32:BD:7C");
```

When I am ready, I connect to the arduino:

```
arduino.connectGatt(this.getActivity(), true, gattCallback);
```

I implement my GATT callback:

```
 private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            final TextView instructionText = getView().findViewById(R.id.instructionText);
            Log.i("DEVICES", "Status: " + status);
            switch (newState) {
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    Log.i("DEVICES", "STATE_CONNECTED");
                    instructionText.setText("Connected. Select Exercise");
                    gatt.discoverServices();
                    break;

                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    Log.i("DEVICES", "STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                    instructionText.setText("acsAssist Disconnected");
                    break;

                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    Log.i("DEVICES", "CONNECTING");
                    instructionText.setText("Connecting to acsAssist...");
                    break;

                default:
                    Log.i("DEVICES", "STATE_OTHER");
                    instructionText.setText("acsAssist Disconnected");
            }
        }
```

I perform my desired actions for service discovery:

```
        @Override
        // New services discovered
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.i("DEVICES", "Services Found");
                for (BluetoothGattService service: gatt.getServices()) {
                    Log.i("DEVICES", service.getUuid().toString());
                }
                for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic: gatt.getService(UUID.fromString("00001826-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")).getCharacteristics()) {
                    gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
                    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
//                    descriptor.setValue(true ? BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE : new byte[]{0x00, 0x00});
                    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);

                    gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
                }
            }
        }
```

And I implement my reading of the characteristic, specifically so that I can monitor it as it is being changed via `onCharacteristicChanged`

```
  @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            //super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
            //gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            Float tester = characteristic.getFloatValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_SFLOAT,1);
            Log.i("UUID", String.valueOf(tester));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
            TextView instructionText = getView().findViewById(R.id.instructionText);
            instructionText.setText(String.valueOf(characteristic.getFloatValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_SFLOAT,1)));

        }
```